# Changing a modem/router gate way to router only

Tags: router

OK. I have a century link C2100T DSL router/modem. I want to use it as a stand alone router. I have a modem connected to the incoming coax and computer,so do not want to use modem in gateway.So, do I just connect a cable to the WAN port on gateway and to modem and that is it?
C2100T has WAN Ethernet port. Would like to use it as a router connected to stand alone modem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried connecting the WAN port as you mention? If not, why not? If it works, it works. If it doesn't: You have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a dedicated WAN Ethernet port – yes, its firmware is already built to be used this way; it'll use whichever of the two WAN interfaces succeeds at getting an IP address.

Comment: It does have a Wan Ethernet port.

Comment: OK, I tried just connecting the ethernet cable to the modem and to the wan port on router. does not work. Is there something I have to change in the router settings?